# Is passing Context as a parameter to a method in a Singleton class causes memory leak

Tags: java, android, singleton

I'm declaring a Singleton class where I need to pass context parameter for one of the methods in this class

```
public class MySingleton() {
    Private Context mContext;
    Private static MySingleton mInstance;

    public static MySingleton mInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MySingleton();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void myMethod(Context context)
    {   
       this.mContext = context;
       // write your code here....
     }
}
```

will this cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could, as you do not know what sort of `Context` you will be referencing. It would be safer to write:

```
this.mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
```

This way, you are certain that `mContext` is referencing the `Application` singleton.

Comment: What if I deleted mContext and kept context as a local variable?

Comment: @HmH: That may be safe, though it would depend a bit on what you do with that variable.

Comment: This method is called to create an AlarmManager and the context is used to initiate an intent and PendingIntent. But the method is called 3 times from 3 different places.

Comment: @HmH: What you are describing should be safe, particularly if you are not holding onto any of those things in fields of your singleton. You can always use tools like Leak Canary to try to see if you are leaking a context.