# How i can use context in Singleton?

Tags: android, object, kotlin

I need in my Singleton -> Context. I know that I can't passing argument in constructor, because object hasn't constructor.

Then I call it from my Application class.

**Here is the code:**

```
object Singleton {

    var userAgentInfo: String = UserAgentTools.buildUserAgent(context)

    fun initializeSdk() {
        AuthenticatorApiManager.initializeSdk(userAgentInfo)
    }
}
```

Comment: there are a few similar questions to this one on SO, have you tried them ?

Comment: like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54075649/access-application-context-in-companion-object-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the initialization of userAgentInfo to the initializeSDK method, and send the Context as an argument, make sure to send the ApplicationContext.

```
object Singleton {

    var userAgentInfo: String? = null

    fun initializeSdk(context: Context) {
        userAgentInfo = UserAgentTools.buildUserAgent(context)
        AuthenticatorApiManager.initializeSdk(userAgentInfo)
    }
}
```

Comment: It can causes memory leak. see 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56102382/is-passing-context-as-a-parameter-to-a-method-in-a-singleton-class-causes-memory]

Comment: It will cause memory leak in case the context is an activity or something similar, but the application context is already in memory in the whole life cycle of the application , and the singletone will be destroyed when the application is destroyed with the application context

Comment: Yeah. If you passing application context then will not be any problem.

Comment: Use `context.applicationContext` within this function to be safe. Then you don't have to worry about what kind of context is passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Make Application class and write below code.

```
companion object {
    private lateinit var sInstance: ApplicationClass
    fun getInstance(): ApplicationClass {
        return sInstance
    }
}
```

Use in object like below.

```
ApplicationClass.getInstance()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use context in your Singleton class using `Application` class instance.[here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60337688/7498057)