# Kotlin is it possible to start an activity from a class?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to kotlin, i am creating a framework to handle all my api call, the problem is that it doesn't have context. I would like to start an activity when i receive a certaine call of the api but i have no activity so i can't Intent.
What i have tried :

```
val intent = Intent(this, testActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

But it's that that i need context.
I also tried to create a global Class Application with a companion object context but i get an error Required Context found Intent.

```
val intent = Intent(App.context, testActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

Is there a way to start an activity in a class ? or what should i do ?

Comment: pass in context and use that to start the activity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I start an Activity from a non-Activity class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298225/how-can-i-start-an-activity-from-a-non-activity-class)

Comment: OK i ll try it but is it a good practice to pass context? because it's doesn't seem safe and i might have leaks ?

Comment: passing context is fine as long as you don't keep a static instance of it

Answer (score 1):

Create Application class and create instance.

```
@Synchronized
        fun getInstance(): MyApplication ? {
            return mInstance
    }
```

Initialize in Application's `onCreate()` method

```
override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        mInstance = this
    }
```

Now use instance as your context in your whole app

```
MyApplication.getInstance()
```

Comment: Why is getInstance method Syncronized?

Answer (score 0):

From your activity, pass `applicationContext` as a parameter to your API class when creating an instance of the API class. You can do this via constructor injection. You can then use the received `applicationContext` to start activities and services